# Populate dropdown from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop

I am trying to populate a dropdown selection with entries from a database table.
The **database table**:

```
TABLE `events` (
    `event_id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `event_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `event_desc` TEXT,
    `event_location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `event_requirements` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
```

The code (in MVC architecture):
**Controller**

```
function index()
    {
        $overview_model = $this->loadModel('Events');
        $this->view->dog_types = $overview_model->getEventTypes();
        $this->view->render('events/index');
    }
```

**Model**

```
public function getEventTypes()
    {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT event_id, event_title FROM events");
        $sth->execute();

        $events = array();

        foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $event) {
            $events[$event->event_id] = new stdClass();
            $events[$event->event_id]->event_title = $event->event_title;
        }
        return $events;
    }
```

**View**

```
    <select>
        <?php foreach ($this->events as $event) {
            echo "<option value='" .$event->event_title. "'>" .$event->event_title."</option>";
        }?>
    </select>
```

**The error** I am getting:

> Notice: Undefined property: View::$events
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I am really new to all this and would be very happy for any kind of help! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. You haven't got a property called $events. You populated a property called

```
$this->view->dog_types
```

And in your view you will be able to access the object like this:

```
  <select>
        <?php foreach ($this->dog_types as $event) { //or $events as $event depending what you indexed as
            echo "<option value='" .$event->event_title. "'>" .$event->event_title."</option>";
        }?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!! I had been looking at the code for so long that I did not spot that!

Comment: Are you using CI? If not I will change the answer

Comment: OK cut all the CI related stuff

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would like to know which framework you are using?
This error comes because you have not passed the events to your respective view.
When you are rendering any view at that time you have to pass the variables which you want to use on view. As per your statement

**$this->view->dog_types = $overview_model->getEventTypes();**

this means you are saving events in **dog_types** variable and you are trying to access it by using **events.**

Comment: Great! Thank you! Mike Miller already pointed that out. I just changed dog_types to events in the controller and now it works.

Comment: I cannot up vote your response at the moment because I do not have enough reputation but I will, as soon as I have! Thanks for the help!